# The mongo ruby diver UUID format seems to be differnt from uuid v4?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

The UUID methods of the ruby mongo driver returns a different format when reading them back, as you can also see in the official documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/v2.13/tutorials/bson-v4/index.html#uuid-methods)

Example:

```
uuid_str = "0c1cf2d8-4f0a-435d-b6ef-078a325d95bc"
BSON::Binary.from_uuid(id).to_uuid 
=> "0c1cf2d8-4f0a-435d-b6ef078a325d95bc"
```

As you can see the resulting UUID is missing the forth dash. I am wondering why this is the case and if there is a way to get back the original format with four dashes in it.

My usecase is that clients provide client side generated UUIDs in the format `"0c1cf2d8-4f0a-435d-b6ef-078a325d95bc"` and I want to save them as BSON Binary UUID to save some index size on the _id index. However my api would need to return the UUID in the same string format as it got it from clients, otherwise it does not make much sense. What am I missing here to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-2438) in bson-ruby library.